# Change CSS on one element when class is added on another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I want to add a specific CSS attribute to my submit-button on my comments form when the user is logged in on Wordpress!

When my class `.comment-form` gets the `p class="logged-in-as"` instead of the "standard" `p class="comment-notes"`, I want my `p.form-submit` to get CSS { width: 50%; }

To be honest I'm not really sure if anyone more than me, the Admin, sees the "Logged in as xxx: Log out?" when they are at my site, which removes the commenters information thus messing up my design... but hey, better to be safe than sorry!

As requested I copied the code from the blog, I'm not sure how this helps but when the first `p class`, as stated earlier, changes due to the commenter being logged in I want to add a CSS value to another div.

```
<p class="logged-in-as">
  <a href="www.example.com/wp-admin/profile.php" aria-label="Logged in as Morgan. Edit your profile.">Logged in as Morgan</a>. <a href="www.example.com/wp-login.php?action=logout&amp;redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2FEXAMPLE.com%2Ftwo-days-in-budapest%2F&amp;_wpnonce=3fb7c78c29">Log out?</a>
</p>
<p class="comment-form-comment">
<label for="comment">Comment</label>
```

Comment: can you share anything about your html structure ?

Comment: If the answer is "no" then the question is, likely, off-topic as not providing the code needed to reproduce the problem. If the answer is "yes," then please show the "*[mcve]*" code, the HTML, CSS and JavaScript (the *minimal* but *complete* code that is just enough to reproduce the problem and show enough of your HTML and structure for us to answer the problem).

Comment: Why not check how your blog looks to visitors (using a second browser or incognito window) and save yourself the hassle?

Comment: So ***you*** are *the Admin*?

Comment: @GCyrillus I added more code per request!
Chris-G I develop like that, thus my design getting wrong when I look ath it while being logged in as Admin. 
Yes Andrei-Gheorghiu I'm the Admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are logged in, WordPress automatically adds the "logged-in" class to the body tag. So you can use:

```
body.logged-in p.form-submit {width: 50%;}
```

Comment: Ah what an elegant solution, of course! Thank you, that really solved it easily!